# Removing Multilevel Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

So essentially I am trying to concatenate two data frames in a Jupyter notebook and to do this I am first setting the index for each data frame to be the date. When I do this it looks like I get a multilevel index with the "3_mo" category in an extra dimension. Do I have to change this somehow?

Once both data frames are formatted and have the same dimension of index then I should be able to just use `.concat([df1, df2])` right?

Data Frame 1:

```
       Date     3_Mo
0   1990-01-02  7.83
1   1990-01-03  7.89
2   1990-01-04  7.84
3   1990-01-05  7.79
4   1990-01-08  7.79
```

Data Frame 2:

```
       Date      3_MO
0   1990-01-02  8.375
1   1990-01-03  8.375
2   1990-01-04  8.375
3   1990-01-05  8.375
4   1990-01-08  8.375
```

Data Frame 1 After `set_index('Date')`:

```
            3_Mo
    Date    
1990-01-02  7.83
1990-01-03  7.89
1990-01-04  7.84
1990-01-05  7.79
1990-01-08  7.79
```

**The goal format:** How do I get this?

```
              MDW     ORD
2000-01-01  4384.0  22474.0
2000-02-01  4185.0  21607.0
2000-03-01  4671.0  24535.0
2000-04-01  4419.0  23108.0
2000-05-01  4552.0  23292.0
```

I would like to have it so I just have one row index and the one column index.

[Picture of the Data Frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhOjW.png)

Comment: Can you provide samples of both input dataframes or create some toy dataframe with the problem and show the expected output from this data?

Comment: @Ethan, it's easier for the community to reproduce your problem and find a solution to your problem if you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can find a great guide on how to do that specifically in pandas examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536193/7480990). Make sure you show us your approach, what your input is and what your desired output would look like.

Comment: How do I copy the output of a Jupyter notebook into a code data frame to post in this question?

Comment: Given that your DataFrame is called `df`, you can use `df.to_dict()` to get a dictionary representation of it. Then in your code example you would copy the output of that, so that it looks like this: `df = pd.DataFrame({'your':'copied', 'dict': 'goes here'})`

Comment: Your `Data Frame 1 After set_index('Date'):` doesn't have a multi-index, the index just has a name.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you are saying now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of a multiindex, use the `.reset_index()` method of your `DataFrame` object.

Comment: Just curious, when I go to plot Data Frame 1 after set_index it returns an error saying 'Empty Data Frame: no numeric data to plot" the numeric data is the 3_mo yield though so why is this happening?

Comment: What's the dtype of 3_mo?

Comment: It says that it is a string which I do not understand because to me it looks like floating point data. Also, when I try to reassign the dytype to float it won't let me reassign it.

Comment: That's probably because you have some row for which you have a string in there.

Comment: Is there a way to use a pandas .loc for searching for string data types?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdecimal.html#pandas.Series.str.isdecimal

`df['3_Mo'].loc[~df['3_Mo'].str.isdecimal()]`

Comment: Using this syntax it returned: Name: 3_MO, Length: 7307, dtype: object (a series of length 7300, out of the 7500 total). These returned values still look like floating point numbers though so why are they being classified as strings?

Comment: This goes a bit beyond the scope of this question, I would suggest asking a new question. Also, again - it's much easier for anyone to help you if they have more information, so I encourage you to find a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: I was about to ask a new question on this topic so I could explain it completely, but its seems that I have been banned from asking questions based on some dumb questions I asked on the platform a year ago when I was new to this site. I have gone back to try to edit/fix those questions based on the guidelines you linked to. In the meantime an upvote on my good questions/recommendations on how to fix any you still believe are bad might be helpful. Cheers.

Comment: In the meantime it would be useful if you could add the output to this question, which you can still edit, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` to make the change in the existing dataframe itself.